# Rename the default django table

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Rename the default django table.

I can't change the default table name django_sessions

Could anyone help?

Thanks for listening

**init**.py

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "my_session"
```

> File "/webapps/desk/**init**.py", line 1, in  |     from
> django.contrib.sessions.models import Session |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/models.py",
> line 1, in  |     from django.contrib.sessions.base_session
> import ( |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/base_session.py",
> line 26, in  |     class AbstractBaseSession(models.Model): |
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 108, in **new** |     app_config =
> apps.get_containing_app_config(module) |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
> 253, in get_containing_app_config |     self.check_apps_ready() |
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 136, in check_apps_ready |     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps
> aren't loaded yet.") | django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady:
> Apps aren't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__.py` file under the app folder place that line. not in the models.

```
appname/__init__.py
```

(not in the models.py)

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "your_session_table_name"
```

Comment: Error - File "/webapps/desk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
DESK |     from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
DESK |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/models.py", line 1, in <module>

Comment: Error importing Session

Comment: @marcelo.delta     `./python manage.py sql sessions`  run this command please.

Comment: What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

The Session model is an internal implementation of Django, and you cannot do that. In any scenario you are thinking about, what you can do is use [Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

> There are three styles of inheritance that are possible in Django.
>
> 1. Often, you will just want to use the parent class to hold information
>    that you don’t want to have to type out for each child model. This
>    class isn’t going to ever be used in isolation, so Abstract base
>    classes are what you’re after.
> 2. If you’re subclassing an existing model
>    (perhaps something from another application entirely) and want each
>    model to have its own database table, Multi-table inheritance is the
>    way to go.
> 3. Finally, if you only want to modify the Python-level
>    behavior of a model, without changing the models fields in any way,
>    you can use Proxy models.

Comment: In some posts he informs that it is possible. I'm getting import problem. Thanks for listening

Comment: You're trying to change Django's internal implementation; this is a logical problem. `Session._meta` is private stuff, don't modify that;